# include <jni.h> and compile with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, arm

For reasons given at 
[Android gcc sysroot and linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680791/android-gcc-sysroot-and-linker) for compiling NDK projects on Ubuntu, I am compiling my Android NDK project with  `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`. There are no problems when compiling with no Android-NDK-specific includes, but now to include `jni.h`,

`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -o main.exe main.c -I'path/to/native_app_glue' -I'/path/to/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include'`

I get some cryptic error `undefined reference to __sF`.

Does anyone know what could be wrong or has anyone gotten Android NDK projects with `jni.h` to successfully compile with a standalone toolchain like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you link everything statically, compiling with `arm-linux-gnueabi-` toolchain will not work because Android uses different sonames than Ubuntu.

Comment: could you spell out the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` statement you would use to get this to work?

Comment: Add `-static` to `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`. However, you should be careful about licenses: LGPL requires that you provide object files of your program to anyone who requests them.

Comment: Here is what worked for me `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c ./main.c -o ./main.o -static -g --sysroot='/mnt/hgfs/F/android-ndk-r8d/platforms/android-14/arch-arm'` 
idk how CFLAGS works.